# D3: scale.domain is undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to reproduce a parallel coordinates chart in d3.js by following [this](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/parallel_custom.html) tutorial from d3 js graph gallery and my x and y scale don't seem to be working correctly.
If I try `console.log(x.domain[0])` I get `undefined` and passing a valid value to the `x` scale gives `NaN`. The scales are defined in the following ways:

```
var dimensions = ["Petal_Length", "Petal_Width", "Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width"];

const x = d3.scalePoint()
                    .domain(dimensions)
                    .range([0, width]);

const y = {};
            for (var i in dimensions) {
                var dim_name = dimensions[i];
                y[dim_name] = d3.scaleLinear()
                                .domain([0, 8])
                                .range([height, 0]);
            }
```

Finally I am using a function to set the d attribute as follows:

```
function path(d) {
                return d3.line()(dimensions.map(function(k) { console.log('Retuned from path function: ', k, typeof k, x.domain[0], y['Petal_Width'](d['Petal_Width'])); return [x(k), y[k](d[k])]; }))
            }

svg.selectAll('conceptPaths')
                .data(conceptImportanceData)
                .enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('class', function(d) { return 'line ' + d.Species })
                .attr('d', path)
                .style('fill', 'none')
                .style('stroke', function(d) { return color(d.Species) })
                .style('opacity', '0.6')
                .on('mouseover', highlight)
                .on('mouseout', removeHighlight);
```

I'm quite new to d3 so, can't figure out what I am missing here. Also, the dataset which is a csv looks like below:

```
Sepal_Length,Sepal_Width,Petal_Length,Petal_Width,Species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa
```

Comment: `domain` is not a property, it's a method (`domain()`), you have to use parentheses: `console.log(x.domain()[0])`.

Comment: @Gerardo thank you for that. While that worked, the scale somehow still doesn't give me any values other than NaN while using the same name from the domain. Any pointers on that?

Answer (score 1):

For someone who might be looking for solutions to this kind of a problem.

Thanks to @Gerardo I was able to figure out that domain was indeed working as expected for my scale. I was dynamically fetching the height and width of the svg and they were the ones that were undefined.

Since I was using them to set my range the output from my scale was always `NaN`.